# Testing Trade Entries in BigQuery/SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data set in BigQuery of various pairs of stock prices, and their relative zscores (ordered by date, and in the millions of rows):

```
   +-----+--------+--------+------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
1  | Row | stock1 | stock2 |    date    |  spreadclose  | logspreadreturn  |   zscore20    |
   +-----+--------+--------+------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
2  | 1   | AJRD   | MAS    | 27/12/2010 |  0.537230704  |  0.017358199     | -0.251654379  |
3  | 2   | ABEV   | EFOI   | 27/12/2010 | 41.00585106   |  0.014929275     |  1.950810153  |
4  | 3   | AIRI   | REFR   | 27/12/2010 |  0.537688889  |  0.003638617     |  0.707555834  |
5  | 4   | AEO    | RJF    | 27/12/2010 |  0.35009565   | -0.004321474     |  0.265411543  |
6  | 5   | AFL    | TSU    | 27/12/2010 |  0.771122788  | -0.028202112     |  0.247268645  |
   +----+---------+--------+------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
```

I then take a sample of the stock prices as per below. I am trying to calculate the trade entries as per the "What I want column" in Big query, but can only seem to achieve the numbers as per the "(Current(Wrong))" column.

```
   Stock1 Stock2     date       zscore20     (Current wrong)   What I want
1    FITB     MS  4/01/2010     -1.5               1           0
2    FITB     MS  5/01/2010     -1.9               1           0
3    FITB     MS  6/01/2010     -2.3               1           1
4    FITB     MS  7/01/2010     -2.0               1           1
5    FITB     MS  8/01/2010     -1.0               1           1
6    FITB     MS 11/01/2010      0.5              -1           0
7    FITB     MS 12/01/2010      1.5              -1           0
8    FITB     MS 13/01/2010      1.8              -1           0
9    FITB     MS 14/01/2010      2.1              -1          -1
10   FITB     MS 15/01/2010      1.5              -1          -1
11   FITB     MS 19/01/2010      1.3              -1          -1
12   FITB     MS 20/01/2010      0.4              -1          -1
13   FITB     MS 21/01/2010     -0.1               1           0
```

The logic in the "What I want column" is as follows:

- In the time series, when zscore > 2.0, flag -1; then exit (0) when zscore next crosses zero into negative
- In the time series, when zscore < -2.0, flag +1; then exit (0) when zscore next crosses zero into postitve

My current query that I run on the larger dataset (setting process year to 2010):

```
DECLARE processyear date;

SET processyear = '2012-01-01'; 

INSERT INTO `dataset.main.tradetime`(

-- Calculate tradetimeparameters
WITH tradetimeparameters AS (
SELECT 
    stock1,
    stock2,
    date,
    spreadclose,
    LN(spreadclose) - LN(LAG(spreadclose) OVER (PARTITION BY stock1, stock2 ORDER BY date ASC)) as logspreadreturn,
    SAFE_DIVIDE((spreadclose - sma20), stdev20) as zscore20
FROM `rw-algotrader-264713.mlbprices.dailyspreads`
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(processyear, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and date < DATE_ADD(processyear, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
),

secondtradetimeparameters AS (
SELECT 
    stock1,
    stock2,
    date,
    spreadclose,
    logspreadreturn,
    zscore20,
    CASE WHEN zscore20 > 0 THEN -1 WHEN zscore20 < 0 THEN 1 END as tradesignal20
FROM tradetimeparameters
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(processyear, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and date < DATE_ADD(processyear, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
),


thirdtradetimeparameters AS (
SELECT 
    stock1,
    stock2,
    date,
    spreadclose,
    logspreadreturn,
    zscore20,
    LEAD(tradesignal20) OVER (PARTITION BY stock1, stock2 ORDER BY date ASC) as tradesignal20
FROM secondtradetimeparameters
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(processyear, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and date < DATE_ADD(processyear, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
),

fourthtradetimeparameters AS (
SELECT 
    stock1,
    stock2,
    date,
    spreadclose,
    logspreadreturn,
    zscore20,
    tradesignal20,
    CASE WHEN tradesignal20 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE tradesignal20 END as positivesignals,
    CASE WHEN tradesignal20 > 0 THEN 0 ELSE tradesignal20 END as negativesignals
FROM thirdtradetimeparameters
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(processyear, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and date < DATE_ADD(processyear, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
),

fifthtradetimeparameters AS (
SELECT 
    stock1,
    stock2,
    date,
    spreadclose,
    logspreadreturn,
    zscore20,
    tradesignal20,
    positivesignals,
    negativesignals,
       (case when positivesignals = 0 then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by stock1,stock2, positivesignals, grp order by date ASC)
        end) as positivedaysintrade
from (select stock1,
    stock2,
    date,
    spreadclose,
    logspreadreturn,
    zscore20,
    tradesignal20,
    positivesignals,
    negativesignals, countif(positivesignals = 0) over (partition by stock1,stock2 order by date ASC) as grp
      from fourthtradetimeparameters
     ) fourthtradetimeparameters
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(processyear, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and date < DATE_ADD(processyear, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
),

sixthtradetimeparameters AS (
SELECT 
    stock1,
    stock2,
    date,
    spreadclose,
    logspreadreturn,
    zscore20,
    tradesignal20,
    positivesignals,
    negativesignals,
    positivedaysintrade,
       (case when negativesignals = 0 then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by stock1,stock2, negativesignals, grp order by date ASC)
        end) as negativedaysintrade
from (select stock1,
    stock2,
    date,
    spreadclose,
    logspreadreturn,
    zscore20,
    tradesignal20,
    positivesignals,
    negativesignals, 
    positivedaysintrade,countif(negativesignals = 0) over (partition by stock1,stock2 order by date ASC) as grp
      from fifthtradetimeparameters
     ) fifthtradetimeparameters
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(processyear, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and date < DATE_ADD(processyear, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
),

seventhtradetimeparameters AS (
SELECT 
    stock1,
    stock2,
    date,
    spreadclose,
    logspreadreturn,
    zscore20,
    tradesignal20,
    positivesignals,
    negativesignals,
    positivedaysintrade,
    negativedaysintrade,
    (positivedaysintrade + negativedaysintrade) as daysintrade,
    (tradesignal20 * logspreadreturn) as sdcreturn20

FROM sixthtradetimeparameters
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(processyear, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and date < DATE_ADD(processyear, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
)

SELECT 
  stock1,
  stock2,
  date,
  spreadclose,
  logspreadreturn,
  zscore20,
  tradesignal20,
  positivesignals,
  negativesignals,
  positivedaysintrade,
  negativedaysintrade,
  daysintrade,
  sdcreturn20
FROM seventhtradetimeparameters)
```

The second shorter table is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `dataset.tradetime` WHERE stock1 = 'FITB' and stock2 = 'MS' and date >= '2010-01-01'
```

[image]

Will appreciate if someone can guide me on the Bigquery/SQL code that can achieve the above. Many thanks in advance,

Comment: A query that generates your current results would really help.  The relationship between your table and desired results is quite unclear.

Comment: Hi Gordon - do the above code segments assist? Still learning SQL, so appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume you are starting with a table that has the first four columns.

Then you can use window functions.  If I understand the conditions, they boil down to:

- `flag = -1` when zscore20 < -2.0 or
- `flag = -1` when zscore20 < 0.0 and there is no non-negative value since the most recent time with a score less than -2.0

And then similar logic for `flag = 1`.

If I'm understanding this correctly, then you can use window functions and `case` expressions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when zscore20 > 2.0
             then 1
             when zscore20 > 0 and
                  (max(case when zscore20 > 2.0 then date end) over (partition by stock1, stock2 order by date) >
                   max(case when zscore20 < 0 then date end) over (partition by stock1, stock2 order by date)
                  )
             then 1
             when zscore20 < -2.0
             then -1
             when zscore20 < 0 and
                  (max(case when zscore20 < -2.0 then date end) over (partition by stock1, stock2 order by date) >
                   max(case when zscore20 > 0 then date end) over (partition by stock1, stock2 order by date)
                  )
             then 1
             else 0 
       end) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon - will try it out - would this segment replace the existing tradesignal flag?. I have also included a diagram in my original question to make things a little easier

Comment: Also, can I ask what the time field in `then time end` is - do I need to declare it?

Comment: @RashKel . . . That should have been `date`.  This replaces all the logic, given that you have the four columns specified.

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks Gordon, I replaced it with date, and it worked perfectly. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Stock1, Stock2, dt_date, zscore20,
  IFNULL(
    LAST_VALUE(flag IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY Stock1, Stock2 ORDER BY dt_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  , 0) What_I_want
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    CASE
      WHEN zscore20 > 2.0 THEN -1
      WHEN zscore20 < -2.0 THEN 1
      WHEN zscore20 >= 0 AND prev_zscore20 < 0 THEN 0
      WHEN zscore20 < 0 AND prev_zscore20 >= 0 THEN 0
      ELSE NULL
    END flag
  FROM (
    SELECT Stock1, Stock2, dt_date, zscore20,
      LAG(zscore20) OVER(PARTITION BY Stock1, Stock2 ORDER BY dt_date) prev_zscore20
    FROM (
      SELECT *, PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt) dt_date
      FROM `project.dataset.table`
    )
  )
)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'FITB' Stock1, 'MS' Stock2, '4/01/2010' dt, -1.5 zscore20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '5/01/2010', -1.9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '6/01/2010', -2.3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '7/01/2010', -2.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '8/01/2010', -1.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '11/01/2010', 0.5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '12/01/2010', 1.5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '13/01/2010', 1.8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '14/01/2010', 2.1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '15/01/2010', 1.5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '19/01/2010', 1.3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '20/01/2010', 0.4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FITB', 'MS', '21/01/2010', -0.1 
)
SELECT Stock1, Stock2, dt_date, zscore20,
  IFNULL(
    LAST_VALUE(flag IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY Stock1, Stock2 ORDER BY dt_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  , 0) What_I_want
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    CASE
      WHEN zscore20 > 2.0 THEN -1
      WHEN zscore20 < -2.0 THEN 1
      WHEN zscore20 >= 0 AND prev_zscore20 < 0 THEN 0
      WHEN zscore20 < 0 AND prev_zscore20 >= 0 THEN 0
      ELSE NULL
    END flag
  FROM (
    SELECT Stock1, Stock2, dt_date, zscore20,
      LAG(zscore20) OVER(PARTITION BY Stock1, Stock2 ORDER BY dt_date) prev_zscore20
    FROM (
      SELECT *, PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt) dt_date
      FROM `project.dataset.table`
    )
  )
)
-- ORDER BY dt_date
```

with result

```
Row Stock1  Stock2  dt_date     zscore20    What_I_want  
1   FITB    MS      2010-01-04  -1.5        0    
2   FITB    MS      2010-01-05  -1.9        0    
3   FITB    MS      2010-01-06  -2.3        1    
4   FITB    MS      2010-01-07  -2.0        1    
5   FITB    MS      2010-01-08  -1.0        1    
6   FITB    MS      2010-01-11  0.5         0    
7   FITB    MS      2010-01-12  1.5         0    
8   FITB    MS      2010-01-13  1.8         0    
9   FITB    MS      2010-01-14  2.1         -1   
10  FITB    MS      2010-01-15  1.5         -1   
11  FITB    MS      2010-01-19  1.3         -1   
12  FITB    MS      2010-01-20  0.4         -1   
13  FITB    MS      2010-01-21  -0.1        0
```

Comment: Many thanks Mikhail - I accepted Gordon's answer as he had replied first and it worked, but do appreciate your response too

Comment: @RashKel - with all respect to Gordon as he is super-expert in SQL - I just checked Gordon's answer again and in no way it produces the expected output! - that was actually reason for me to jump and provide "working" answer